# incompatible data type in conversion in hsqldb when query IS NULL with java.sql.Timestamp with spring-data-jpa 2.6.2

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, timestamp, hsqldb

spring-boot-starter-data-jpa 2.6.4 has a dependency to spring-data-jpa 2.6.2 which has a dependency to hsqldb 2.5.2 and hibernate 5.6.7.Final

when we want to query mutliple values of type java.sql.Timestamp in a CrudRepository, i.e.

```
@Query("SELECT dm " +
        " FROM DataModel dm " +
        "WHERE (dm.ts1 IS NULL OR :ts1 IS NULL OR dm.ts1 < :ts1) " +
        "  AND (dm.ts2 IS NULL OR :ts2 IS NULL OR dm.ts2 < :ts2)")
List<DataModel> findByTimestamps(@Param("ts1") Timestamp ts1, @Param("ts2") Timestamp ts2);
```

it fails with
`org.hsqldb.HsqlException: incompatible data type in conversion`

this also happens with spring-data-jpa 2.6.3

downgrade to hsqldb 2.5.1 works

Repo for reproduce:
https://github.com/daveyx/spring-data-hsqldb-timestamp-issue

The problem occurs in `org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement#setTimestamp(int, java.sql.Timestamp, java.util.Calendar)` because of a wrong parameterType.

It looks like the "IS NULL" part of the @Param annotated parameter leads to a "CharacterType" instead of a "DateTimeType" in JDBCPreparedStatement#setTimestamp.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned, the problem is caused by the conditions `OR :ts1 IS NULL` and `OR :ts2 IS NULL`. Hibernate applies these to the SQL query in the form `? IS NULL` and HSQLDB resolves the parameter as String. Hibernate then assumes the parameter type is resolved to java.sql.Timestamp and calls the setTimestamp(int, Timestamp) method, which causes the problem.

You can add CAST to determine the type of the parameter.

```
@Query("SELECT dm " +
    " FROM DataModel dm " +
    "WHERE (dm.ts1 IS NULL OR CAST(:ts1 AS TIMESTAMP) IS NULL OR dm.ts1 < :ts1) " +
    "  AND (dm.ts2 IS NULL OR CAST(:ts2 AS TIMESTAMP) IS NULL OR dm.ts2 < :ts2)")
```

HSQLDB version 2.5.1 was lenient with `setTimestamp(int, Timestamp)` and converted the timestamp to a String when the target was not a timestamp. A regression in version 2.5.2 and 2.6.0 made it strict. Future versions of HSQLDB will revert to the lenient approach.

Comment: thanks for answer, for me this is a bug as version update makes existing code fail. hsqld should not fail on NULL, it should ignore the datatype. we don't want to change code, so we will stay on 2.5.1

Comment: do you happen to have a link to the issue tracker for the regression?

Comment: Issue tracker link: https://sourceforge.net/p/hsqldb/bugs/1641/